NextUI `isClearable` is not working at all
I'm using NextUI with react-hook-form in a Next.JS project. I used isClearable. It's showing a cross mark on the field when filled, but it's not working.
<Controller
  control={control}
  name="username"
  render={({ field }) => (
    <Input
      {...field}
      isClearable
      className="mb-3"
      errorMessage={errors.username?.message?.toString()}
      isInvalid={!!errors.username?.message?.toString()}
      label={<strong>Username</strong>}
      placeholder="Enter your username"
      variant="underlined"
    />
  )}
/>


The isClearable is not directly meant to clear the field, it's actually for showing a cross icon to the edge of the field when the field is filled. The actual 'clear' thing has to be done explicitly. Here's the revised code that will clear the field using the cross icon.
<Controller
  control={control}
  name="username"
  render={({ field }) => (
    <Input
      {...field}
      isClearable
      className="mb-3"
      errorMessage={errors.username?.message?.toString()}
      isInvalid={!!errors.username?.message?.toString()}
      label={<strong>Username</strong>}
      placeholder="Enter your username"
      variant="underlined"
      onClear={() => field.onChange("")}
    />
  )}
/>

On the onClear property, the field.onChange method provided by react-hook-form automatically updates the form's value without needing a separate state variable.
